Not able to see wordpress dashboard after changing the localhost name
I am developing a website on WordPress Localhost (i.e. on my laptop only).
(1) Today I changed the localhost name from "marathishala" to "8vimarathi" from wordpress menu itself.
(2) Then I changed names of all folders having name "marathishala" to "8vimarathi" in "xampp" folder.
(3) Also changed name of database folder from "marathishaladb" to "8vimarathidb".
(4) Also changed entry in wp-config.php file from "define( 'DB_NAME', 'marathishala' )" to "define( 'DB_NAME', '8vimarathi' )"
But now when I use URL: http://localhost/8vimarathi/wp-admin/, I am getting error shown in the attached screenshot.
Could you please help to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

You say  (3) Also changed name of database folder from "marathishaladb" to "8vimarathidb".
If this was to change the database name, it doesn't work like that.  You need to use PHPMyAdmin or something similar, and rename the database there.
